# angular 6 universal app production build Error

Tags: angular, angular6

I have recently migrated my angular 5 universal apps, to angular 6, I created it using **ng generate universal command** and followed below git hub link.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/universal-rendering.md#step-4-setting-up-an-express-server-to-run-our-universal-bundles

when I am running build command it showing error...

```
npm run build:SSR
```

**Error: __**

```
ERROR in ./server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main.bundle' in 'F:\angular_univarsal_tvtrd'
 @ ./server.ts 20:9-45
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also upgraded from Angular 5 to 6 and I had the issue when building for universal. What I did was to download the sample app from the angular universal wiki and compared the files that I have with the ones discussed on the [wiki](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

It could be so many reasons why the build won't work for example, I have noticed one of my mistakes was with the script

```
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run MY-APP-NAME:server",
```

I had copied and pasted the one from the wiki but the name of my app was different. I have corrected this as my previous script was still using the  `--app` which is no longer used but we now scope using `--project` as you can see the change in the new `angular.json` file which has a property of **projects** instead of **apps**.

Another thing could be that in your `server.ts` file you still have

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');
```

instead of

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');
```

Thus the best way I have solved this issue was to follow exactly what they are doing in the wiki and also compare the package versions they are using and updated mines to match their packages in the `package.json` those that are concerning Angular

Hope that'll help